# Android Source code download error

Tags: android, ubuntu

I have followed the instructions on the Android website on how to download the latest android source code files but it gives errors when i run this command:

```
repo init -u git://android2.git.kernel.org/platform/manifest.git
```

It gives the following error:

```
Getting repo ...
from git://android.git.kernel.org/tools/repo.git
android.git.kernel.org[0: 199.6.1.176]: errno=Connection refused
android.git.kernel.org[0: 130.239.17.12]: errno=Connection refused
fatal: unable to connect a socket (Connection refused)
```

On checking forums for its resolution, i was told that port 9418 was being blocked.
I use Ubuntu 10.04 and ensured that the firewall wasnt blocking the port and also enabled the port and the above IP addresses.
I also spoke to the networking peeps who ensured that no traffic from the internet is being blocked.
I would be glad if i could get directions on how to proceed next.

Comment: Please note that android.git.kernel.org is no longer the address from which Android is distributed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I fixed this.

Download and install Corkscrew, using `sudo apt-get install corkscrew`.

I had earlier created and added a bin directory under my home directory which also contains the repo script.

Create a "git-proxy" script and add the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec corkscrew 67.202.81.240 8080 $*
```

The IP address can be got from a website that provides free proxy address on the internet.
The website is listed here: http://spys.ru/en/

After that, execute the following command:

```
git config --global core.gitproxy '~/bin/git-proxy'
```

Re-run: `repo init -u git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/manifest.git`

Then run `repo sync`.

Comment: could you please help me with - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21600830/ssh-ing-to-remote-server-from-behind-a-proxy

Answer (score 0):

Try using **"http://" instead of "git://".** It worked for me!

Perhaps your or local networks' firewall is blocking port 9418.

Found this..

http://groups.google.com/group/repo-discuss/browse_thread/thread/385411eddb126c39

"Some ISPs may block non-HTTP network connections in an attempt to stop illegal file sharing from taking up too much network bandwidth. Unfortunately this also means their customers are blocked from performing legal file sharing activity, such as participating in an open source project. Talk to whoever supplies your Internet connection about why TCP port 9418 is not being allowed."

Comment: Please don't edit to hide link targets when knowing what the link is to is an important part of judging its relevance.